# Signs are always blank when closing keyboard in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Kindle Fire HD and I have Minecraft Pocket Edition. I have a problem with my signs. I place them on both game modes fine,and I also type them fine, but when I exit my keyboard, the sign is blank. This always happens and I have even tried downloading maps, but the signs on those are blank too.

Comment: What did you press when you exiting your keyboard? You should press "Done" on the keyboard / GUI.

Comment: What minecraft PE version? Some early alpha version may have this glich